# When refreshing an Oracle read only materialised view, is access to old data blocked

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

As I understand it, an Oracle readonly materialised view is similar to a real view, but it contains a full snapshot of the source data - stored in a similar way to a table. To update the snapshot, an Oracle command can be invoked to refresh the materialised view's contents from its source.

The question is, during a refresh, is the materialised view blocked from being read, or will the update be applied in an isolated fashion, allowing the old snapshot to still be read while the update is taking place?

Comment: check out the atomic_refresh option.

Answer (score 3):

Into Oracle writers don't block readers. Never. It's main advantage of versioning as is. Physically it looks same as if you update the table while somebody selects from it.

Btw, you can just try. Make MV with long refresh time and check if you can read it while refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle there are possible two ways how to cleanup the MV before refresing

- truncate (DDL), DDL commits, so someone might see MV empty during refresh
- delete(DML) is transactional, so users will either see old or new version of data.

As noted by @GriffeyDog see atomic_refresh option.